# Ошибка с идентификатором ресурса в ImageView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться почему выдает ошибку в R.drawable.lazer1 ?

```
public void setImgView(View v) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(id.lazer1);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.lazer1);
}
```

Указано в xml-файле:

```
ImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/lazer1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lazer1"
```

в папку `drawable` переместил рисунок `lazer1.png`

В качестве ошибки пишет:
`setImageDravable (android.graphics.dravable.Dravable) in ImageView cannot be applied to  (int)`

В чем заключается проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше:

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lazer1);
```

Comment: не лучше, а это и есть тот метод, который принимает на вход id ресурса у ImageView, а тот, что автор вопроса использует, это метод, которому на вход подается Dravable.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что:

Во первых - вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к *Android Studio*, так как это всего лишь одна из IDE - инструмент разработчика. Точно такую же ошибку вы получите при компиляции даже если будете писать свою программу в Блокноте.

Во вторых - метод `setImageDrawable()` в качестве аргумента принимает объект типа `Drawable`, вы же ему пытаетесь подсунуть идентификатор ресурса, который имеет тип `int` и никак не годится в качестве аргумента для этого метода.

Для того, чтобы `ImageView` принял в качестве аргумента идентификатор ресурса, как вы хотите, следует использовать другой метод - `setImageResource()`

В третьих - раз уж вы помянули *Android Studio*, то эта IDE предоставляет исчерпывающую информацию по сигнатурам методов и подсказывает какого типа аргументы ожидает тот или иной из них, как раз для того, чтобы программист не делал таких ошибок, что произошла с вами. Возможностями современных средств разработки можно (и нужно) пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Вставляй не R.drawable.lazer1 , а Bitmap.convertFromResource(R.drawable.lazer1)...т.е вставляй не int, а Bitmap